# Use external drive as a folder in nginx

Tags: permissions, mount

I'm trying to mount an external drive on a web folder, call it `flash`:
[image]

After mounting the external drive which is located in `/dev/sdb1` the permissions change like this:

> sudo mount -o defaults /dev/sdb1 /var/www/html/TV/flash

[image]

When I try to browse a file from the mounted location, I get `404 Not Found` while the file exists.

[image]

When I try to list files inside the folder it says *Permission Denied*

[image]

Also, I have tried changing the ownership of the folder, but didn't work:

> sudo chown -R "$USER":www-data flash/
>
> chown: changing ownership of 'flash/System Volume Information': Read-only file system
>
> chown: changing ownership of 'flash/': Read-only file system

Comment: I tried this https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-finding-using-uuids-to-update-fstab/ but didn't work.

Comment: I formatted the flash disk as FAT then everything worked, except changing the ownership. which says ```Operation not permitted``` tho I'm using ```sudo```

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between `folder` `folder\`

`folder\` means things inside the folder not the folder itself. `folder` indicates the folder only not the files and sub-directory residing inside it. But as you're using the `chown` command recursively ownership of all sub-directory and file inside `folder` will also be changed.

So typing the following shall solve the situation

```
sudo chown -R "$USER":www-data /var/www/html/TV/flash
```

Also change files permission. Your're making `$USER` as owner and `www-data` as group owner. And your existing permission showing `500` for the directory. So only owner and not the group owner can search through the directory. and your we server is running under the group owner `www-data`

A good practice is keeping all directory permission as `755` and files permission as `644`.

```
find /var/www/html/TV/flash -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find /var/www/html/TV/flash -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Comment in case of any error.

Comment: I get the same error. ```Read-only file system```

Comment: Ok. You may try this once `sudo mount -o remount,rw  /dev/sdb1 /var/www/html/TV/flash` after un mounting the already mounted one.